# Meteor Iron Router Wait for template to be rendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

Is there anyway to wait for template to be rendered and then execute certain function?

I have tried after and it doesn't work.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('post', {
    path: '/posts/:ll',

    action: function () {
      this.render('home');
    },

    after: function () {
      var n = this.params.ll
       UI.insert(UI.render(Template[n]), document.getElementById("child"))
    }
  });
});
```

Turns out the child element doesn't exist yet because the 'home' template isn't yet rendered when the after function is fired.

Any suggestion or work around is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onAfterAction` instead of `after`

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#before-and-after-hooks

Comment: Thanks Friday. At the time I wrote the question that feature did not yet exist in iron router. But marked as solved for others.

Comment: As of 0.8.3 and last revision of iron-router, it seems template instance is not rendered when onAfterAction is executed. Trying to access template elements doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Can you do this:

```
action: function () {
  this.render('home');
  Template.home.rendered = function() {
    // ...
    Template.home.rendered = null;
  };
},
```

Comment: Thanks! the accepted answer was not working for me, but this did